# Edit text only by toolbar

Tags: javascript, summernote

As title, I'm building a website, which user can only edit the text only by toolbar.

As user press a button, the website gives an article and letting user to highlight (by toolbar button).
But I don't want user to add/delete any word (or space, newline)

I have tried using "disableDragAndDrop", "shortcut" but didn't solve my problem.

Does anyone have some good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i find the solution finally.
`$("#summernote").summernote("disable")` will disable include tollbar.
however, if you analyze it, you can find this:
`class="note-editable" contenteditable="false"`
So, just add
`$(".note-editable").attr("contenteditable", false);`
then everything is done.